# Using re.compile to compile multiple strings in a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to compile this list

```
list_serv = ["no","none","nothing","never"]
```

But I am unable to do it so I have to type each element of that list individually as follows

```
compiled_list_serv = re.compile(r'no\b|not\b|none\b|nothing\b')
```

Can someone please suggest me an efficient code in Python so that I can compile all the elements in list 'list_serv' in one go?

The resultant compilation should look something like this:

```
re.compile(r'no\b|not\b|none\b|nothing\b', re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

From the given code you could do it like this:

```
re.compile("|".join(list_serv), re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: When I try to do re.compile("\b|".join(["no","not","none","nothing"])) I get re.compile(r'no\b|not\b|none\b|nothing', re.UNICODE). But what I want is this re.compile(r'no\b|not\b|none\b|nothing\b', re.UNICODE)

Comment: Then the line would be:
re.compile("".join([s + "\b|" for s in list_serv]), re.UNICODE)

Comment: Nope I got this in return : re.compile(r'no\x08|not\x08|none\x08|nothing\x08|', re.UNICODE)